# Funcion de Jquery con Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen día!

tengo la siguente estructura html:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="item">
        <a href="" class="item-content">
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="sub-item"></li>
                <li class="sub-item"></li>
            </ul>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <a href="" class="item-content">
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="sub-item"></li>
                <li class="sub-item"></li>
            </ul>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Como podría traducir esta función de Jquey a Vanilla Javascript

```
$(".item-content").click(function(){
$(this).children(".down").toggleClass("active")
$(this).toggleClass("active")
$(this).find(".sub-menu").toggleClass("active")
});
```

Lo que hago con esta función es escuchar cuando un elemento con la clase item-content es clickeado, tomo ese elemento y obtengo sus hijos con las clases down y sub menu  y les agrego la clase active esto para que el elemento down haga una animacion y cambiar el display none del elemento sub-menu a display block

He intentado con esto:

```
let $arow = document.querySelector('.down')
$arow.addEventListener('click',() => subMenuToggle())
const subMenuToggle = () =>{
  document.querySelector('.down').classList.toggle('active')
  document.querySelector('.sub-menu').classList.toggle('active')
}
```

Pero esto solo me funciona con el primer elemento, como podría agregar el Event listener a todos los elementos con la clase down?

Comment: Por favor edita y explicanos mejor que es lo que hace tu primer código (el que esta en JQuery)

Comment: querySelector solo te va a coger el primer elemento, querySelectorAll te coje los elementos de la clase por ejemplo y accedes a ellos con [0] para el primero elemento y así.

Comment: Ya he editado la pregunta para explicar que es lo que hago con Jquery, tambien agregue mi estructura html @BetaM

Comment: No tienes elementos con clase _down_ ese código va a dar error, ya sea con jQuery o Javascript puro.